# How do I convert the Column level values into a single row in R?

Tags: r

I have a dataframe similar to below,

```
Name   | ID             |  SET  | COUNT  |
------ | ------         |------ | ------ |
Value  | 44000001005    | 0     | 24     |
Value  | 10000000019659 | 0     | 29     |
Value  | 10000000019659 | 1     | 5      |
```

The result that I need is something like,

```
Name   | ID             |  0    | 1      |
------ | ------         |------ | ------ |
Value  | 44000001005    | 24    | 0      |
Value  | 10000000019659 | 29    | 5      |
```

Can this be done or would I have to re-work the data set? 
I am relatively new to R, so I may have missed some very obvious logic, but would appreciate if anyone could guide me. 
Thank you.

Comment: You'll probably have to be far more specific than that if you want help. I don't understand the question as it's currently written.

Comment: @smacdonald Sorry about that. I have edited the format. Hope it is better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to change the format from a long to a wide format you can use the spread function from the tidyr package. There are other packages and possibilities, but this is my favorite.

If you are new to R, be aware that you have to install the package first with install.packages("tidyr").

```
Name <- c("Value","Value","Value")
ID <- c(6546465445,5464564,5464564)
SET <- c(0,0,1)
COUNT <- c(24,29,5)

df <- cbind.data.frame(Name,ID,SET,COUNT,stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

library(tidyr)

spread(data=df,key=SET,value = COUNT,fill=0) -> df_wide
```

see the documentation ?spread for details about the function.

Comment: This works perfect. Thank you so much. The documentation helped me get a clearer picture of the function.